# Sonata Admin seach block give the following error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i try to use the search block in Sonata admin:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Class does not exist").

and these errors:
 }, {                            'query': query,                            'admin_code': admin.code,                            'page': 0,                            'per_page': 10,                            'icon': group.icon                        }) }}                    {% endif %}                {% endfor %}            {% endif %}        {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is displayed when no entity exists for some Bundle, i mean Bundles without Entities.
I solved this Problem by escaping these Bundles in search.html.twig:

```
{% if admin.code!= 'bundle.admin.bulkcoupon' and  admin.code!='bundle.admin.tools' %}
                        {{ sonata_block_render({
                            'type': 'sonata.admin.block.search_result'
                        }, {
                            'query': query,
                            'admin_code': admin.code,
                            'page': 0,
                            'per_page': 10,
                            'icon': group.icon
                        }) }}
        {% endif %}
```